# How to scale path and photo together in android

Tags: android, graphics, transform, scale, zooming

I'm working for draw on photo android app. I'm trying to add zoom photo and drawn path together.

```kotlin
    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        initialize()
        invalidate()
    }
    
    private fun initialize() {
        viewWidth = measuredWidth.toFloat()
        viewHeight = measuredHeight.toFloat()
        viewRect.set(0f, 0f, measuredWidth.toFloat(), measuredHeight.toFloat())
        initializeBitmapMatrix()
    }
    
    private fun initializeBitmapMatrix() {
        val scale = min(viewWidth / bitmapRect.width(), viewHeight / bitmapRect.height())
        bitmapMatrix.setScale(scale, scale)
    
        val translateX = (viewWidth - bitmapRect.width() * scale) / 2f
        val translateY = (viewHeight - bitmapRect.height() * scale) / 2f
        bitmapMatrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY)
    }
    
    fun setBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap
    
        bitmapRect.set(
                0f,
                0f,
                this.bitmap?.width?.toFloat() ?: 0f,
                this.bitmap?.height?.toFloat() ?: 0f
        )
       
        initialize()
        invalidate()
    }
```

My gesture listener:

```kotlin
override fun onScale(scaleFactor: Float, focusX: Float, focusY: Float) {

        bitmapMatrix.preScale(
                scaleFactor,
                scaleFactor,
                bitmapRect.centerX(),
                bitmapRect.centerY()
        )


        val pathComputeBounds = RectF()
        path.computeBounds(pathComputeBounds, true)

        paint.strokeWidth = paint.strokeWidth * scaleFactor
        pathMatrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor,
                pathComputeBounds.centerX(), pathComputeBounds.centerY()
        )
        path.transform(pathMatrix)

        invalidate()
    }
```

When I zoom photo and path It doesn't scale correctly. You see before zoom/after zoom on photo below. How can I fix this issue?

[image: diff before zoom and after]